# removing a subview

Tags: iphone, release, subview

I have looked on here and found a few examples but nothing works so here goes...
I have a subview which is started and works fine, the camera takes a pic and then a thumbnail appears at the bottom right, when clicked I want the subview released but no matter how I try I can't get rid of the subview!

Code:

```
    -(void)onSingleTap:(UITouch*)touch {
NSLog(@"onSingleTap");
    UIImageView *eyes = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"binocs.png"]] autorelease];
eyes.tag = EYES_TAG;
    [self.overlayView addSubview:eyes];
    [camera takePicture];
    }
```

Then the thumbnail action:

```
    - (void)thumbnailTapped:(id)sender {
    self.view.alpha = 99.0f;    
    UIButton *binocsButton = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:BINOCS_BUTTON_TAG];
binocsButton.hidden = YES;

    }
```

So my subView is called eyes and I just need to clear that view under the thumbnail tapped action. Any ideas would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow entirely, but don't you just want to add this to the bottom of `thumbnailTapped:`:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:EYES_TAG] removeFromSuperview];
```

By the way, rather than using tags it's probably better to store a reference to the views that you want to access as an ivar of your view controller class. I would add this to your property definitions:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *eyes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *binocsButton;
```

Then synthesise them and when you create those objects, assign to the properties and then you can access them easier later. Using tags I found in the past gets quite annoying as if the view is at the bottom of a complex view hierarchy you can't access it easily. If you do do this, remember to also release them in your `dealloc` (unless you're using ARC).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have tried putting that in and still the eyes layer is over the top of the camera view. I don't know what else to try :(

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do to be honest. What do you mean by "the eyes layer is over the top of the camera view"? What camera view? You've not mentioned how your "camera view" appears.

Comment: oh sorry, can I send it privately? I have spent over 30 hours on this part of the code and its really hurting my brain!